# google scripts miscalculates when multiple variables call the same function at the same time

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following google scripts:

```
function doGet() {
  var result1 = {};
  var result2 = {};
  var result3 = {};

  var infected = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Data').getDataRange().getValues();


result1 = makeObject1(infected);
result2 = makeObject2(infected);
result3 = makeObject3(infected);  


var confirmed = sum(result1);
Logger.log( "sum: "+confirmed );  

var death = sum(result2);
Logger.log( "sum: "+death );  

var recovered = sum(result3);
Logger.log( "sum: "+recovered );    

//return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(result)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);




}


function sum(values) {
  var sum = 0;
  for( var el in values ) {
    if( values.hasOwnProperty( el ) ) {
      sum += parseFloat( values[el] );
    }
  }
  return sum;
}



function makeObject1(multiArr) {
  var obj = {};
  var countrystats = {};
  var headers = multiArr.shift();

  for(var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++){
    countrystats[i] = multiArr.map(function(app) {
      return app[i];
    })}

  for(var m = 0; m < countrystats[1].length; m++){
  obj[countrystats[1][m]] = 0;
  }

  for(var j = 0; j < countrystats[1].length; j++){

    var TempVar;
    TempVar = obj[countrystats[1][j]];
    obj[countrystats[1][j]] = TempVar + countrystats[3][j];

  }
  return obj;
}


function makeObject2(multiArr) {
  var obj = {};
  var countrystats = {};
  var headers = multiArr.shift();

  for(var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++){
    countrystats[i] = multiArr.map(function(app) {
      return app[i];
    })}

  for(var m = 0; m < countrystats[1].length; m++){
  obj[countrystats[1][m]] = 0;
  }

  for(var j = 0; j < countrystats[1].length; j++){

    var TempVar;
    TempVar = obj[countrystats[1][j]];
    obj[countrystats[1][j]] = TempVar + countrystats[4][j];

  }
  return obj;
}


function makeObject3(multiArr) {
  var obj = {};
  var countrystats = {};
  var headers = multiArr.shift();

  for(var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++){
    countrystats[i] = multiArr.map(function(app) {
      return app[i];
    })}

  for(var m = 0; m < countrystats[1].length; m++){
  obj[countrystats[1][m]] = 0;
  }

  for(var j = 0; j < countrystats[1].length; j++){

    var TempVar;
    TempVar = obj[countrystats[1][j]];
    obj[countrystats[1][j]] = TempVar + countrystats[5][j];

  }
  return obj;
}
```

When I try to find `result1, result2, and result3` and run the code as it is above, i get the following in the logs:

```
[20-02-02 18:52:25:651 CET] sum: 14549
[20-02-02 18:52:25:652 CET] sum: 11
[20-02-02 18:52:25:652 CET] sum: 102
```

This is inncorrect. When I run only one of them though, it works. (E.g. I comment out result1 and result2, and i get the correct value for result3. or i comment out result1 and result3 and i get the right value for result2. I think result1 is always correct)

the output should be:

```
[20-02-02 18:52:25:651 CET] sum: 14549
[20-02-02 18:52:25:652 CET] sum: 305
[20-02-02 18:52:25:652 CET] sum: 340
```

Comment: Of course these functions behave differently when called using the same argument - they each modify the argument they were given. (Specifically, they remove the first row of the given array...)

Comment: am i missing something?

Comment: Read about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/array/shift

Comment: what part do i remove, so it doesnt remove the first row?

Comment: remove the `shift()`

Comment: Thanks, for help. Sometimes the simple things get you and you just need a new perspective to find them.

Comment: You could use `multiArr[0];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

Array.Shift() Removed the first row. Use this only once to remove headers, and then use Array[0] to access the data.